Maze solving algorithm gets stuck and keeps running in "circles"
I'm trying to implement a maze solving python program:
The maze looks something like this:
│╶┘│┌┐└╴├─┐┌─┐┌┐├┴─╴└─┤┌╴┌┐┌┘├┐└──┘┌─┐┌┘└┤││┌─┐╷└┐┌┘└┐└┐│┌┘│╵├───┐│┌───┐│╵├─┐│││┌─┘│││╷│┌─┐└┘┌┤└──┐│└─┐╷│└┤┌┐└┐│╵│┌──┐┌┘└┐│╷└┘┌┐│╵││└┤┌─┐└┘┌┐┌┬╴┌┘│╶┬┘┌┐│┌┘└┐└┐└┐└┐└┐│╶┬╴└┘└┐└─┐┌┐╶┘┌┘││╶┘┌─┐╵│└┐└┤┌─┐┌─┘│┌───┐├┘│┌┤┌───┐│╷│└┤│└┐┌┘┌─┘│││╵└┐│└┘╶┬┐┌┐┌┘│├┘┌┐╵┌─┘└─┐│╶┬─┤├┘└┐└─┐└┐│┌┐┌─┘┌┘╵│╷└──┐└─┤│┌─┘└┼──┤╷││└┐┌┘└┴─┬┘└┬┘│╷┌┴╴│└─┘│┌─┐│└┐└┐│└┘└┐╶┐│││└┘│┌─┘└──┐├┐╷└┘┌─┤└┐┌┘││└──┐└┘└┘┌┘│┌┘┌┘┌┘┌╴└──┘├┐└──┘│┌┬╴││└─┘┌┐└─┘│┌┐┌┘└┐├─┐┌┐╵│╵┌┐│└╴│╵└──┘└┼─╴└─┐│└┐┌┤│└─┐┌┘┌╴└┐╵│┌─┐┌┘└┤┌─┘│┌─┐╶─┬┘┌───┘┌┘╵└┘││╵┌┘│┌┐└┐┌┐└╴││└┐│┌┬───┘┌┐└┘│┌┐╵┌┤│╶┤╵└┴╴┌──┐│└┐│└┘┌┘└┬╴┌─┤╶┴┤┌┐╵││├┐└┴┐└┘╶┐└┐│└┘╷└┐╵┌──┘├┴╴┌─┘└┐└┐└┘│└┘╷┌┘└┘│└┘╷├╴┌┤╵┌──┘│┌╴└┤└┐└┘└┐│└─┘│┌─┘├──┘││┌─┘└┴─┘├┐││┌┘╷┌┘└┘└─┘╶┴┐├─┘└┘│╶┐└─┘┌┘┌┘┌┘└┐├──┐┌┘╶─┤││┌─┘┌
Obviously it's not this exactly, I just copied a random section of the txt file, but you get the idea, the maze is composed of these characters, the start is at the top left corner and the end is at the bottom right corner
My algorithm idea
I'll try to briefly explain the way my program works so that you have an easier time trying to understand it.
The program keeps track of the current position in the maze, based on the position it figures out the character on which it is currently standing and based on that, it figures out which directions it can go further (get_directions() function), some directions that are invalid are removed from the list returned by the function (direction that would lead back where you came from, directions that lead to a dead end)
The program also keeps track of the path that was taken to where it currently is (["down", "left", "up", "up", etc...])
The program then tries one of the possible directions, it also keeps track of the first encountered crossing (any spot from which there are more than one direction to go, excluding the direction that would lead back) and the last encountered crossroad, the reason for this is that IF the algorithm comes to a dead end (There are 0 possible directions to go) it goes back along the path variable and all the characters along the way back from 0 to 1, which means that that direction leads to a dead end. Once it reaches the last encountered crossroad, it goes back to the first one and tries the move again, this will (hopefully) lead to blocking all of the paths that lead to a dead end, which will lead me to the end.
Now that that's out of the way, here's the code snippets, I'll try and keep them as short as possible
# Based on the character, returns a list of possible move directions
def get_moves(maze ,pos):
    c = maze[pos[0]][pos[1]][0]
    if c == '─':
        d = ["left", "right"]
        return d
    elif c == '╶':
        d = ["right"]
        return d
    elif c == '╴':
        d = ["left"]
    # And the rest of the characters...

# Checks whether position to move to is blocked or available (position is only blocked if it leads nowhere)
def check_path(maze, pos, mv):
    print(f"checking move '{mv}'...")
    tmp_pos = move(mv, pos)
    if opposite(mv) not in get_moves(maze, tmp_pos) or maze[tmp_pos[0]][tmp_pos[1]][1] == 1:
        return False # Path is invalid or blocked
    return True # Path is not blocked

# Returns the list of possible moves except for the last move made (To prevent going back and forth) and those moves that lead to a blocked path
def exclude_invalid(moves, last_move, maze, pos):
    for m in moves: # for each 'm'ove in moves
        if check_path(maze, pos, m) == False: # Check if path is valid
            moves.remove(m)
    if opposite(last_move) in moves:
        moves.remove(opposite(last_move))
        if moves == []:
            return ["empty"]
        return moves
    else:
        return moves

# Returns the position to the first encoutered crossroad and blocks each block until the last encoutered crossroad is passed
def backtrack(crossf, crossl, pos, path, maze):
    crossl_check = False
    rev_path = list(map(lambda x: opposite(x), path[::-1]))
    i = 0
    while pos != crossf:
        print("Backtracking...")
        if pos == crossl:
            crossl_check = True
        if crossl_check == False:
            maze[pos[0]][pos[1]][1] = 1
        pos = move(rev_path[i], pos)
        i += 1
    return maze, pos

And here's the main loop
# Main loop
while pos != end: # While position is not equal to the end position
    print(pos)
    moves = get_moves(maze, pos)
    moves = exclude_invalid(moves, last_move, maze, pos)
    for m in moves:
        # If the only way is to go back (this direction is a dead end)
        if m == "empty":
            maze, pos = backtrack(crossroad_first, crossroad_last, pos, path, maze)
            last_move = ""
            break
        if len(moves) > 1: # Position is a crossroad
            crossroad_last = pos.copy()
        # If path was not blocked
        if check_path(maze, pos, m) == True:
            print("Moving...")
            last_move = m
            pos = move(m, pos)
            path.append(m)
            break
        # If path was blocked, try the next direction
        else:
            continue

The problem
When I run the code, it seems to work just fine, but after a while, it gets stuck on [3, 11], which is this character ┼
The code doesn't want to move and I have no idea why...
Any ideas?
EDIT:
Here's a link to a github repository containing the maze file (tmp.txt) and the entirety of the python code so you can try and reproduce the problem yourself.
https://github.com/Brews-Lee/maze-solver
Thank you all very much for your willingness to help me!

Are there newlines missing in "The maze looks like this"?

Please show the input in code. Keeping snippets short is good, but they still need to be complete and runnable (and minimal).

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

@BrewsLee, your question is interesting, and we might be able to help, we just need you to provide more details, specially the sample input/output properly formatted. If you submit an edit, you can get this reopened.
